# CSS span height 100% inside table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've got a table.
Inside the table I've got `<a class="available">available</a>`,
but it seems the height doesn't cover the whole table row.

html:

```
<table with="100%" class="list_table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><a class="available">Available</a></td>
<td><a class="booked"><span>Nose to mouth</span><span>Frown Lines</span></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

css:

```
.list_table thead th, .list_table tbody td { border:1px solid #D3D9CB;  font-size:12px; position:relative !important;}
.available { background:#98AEB3; display:block; height:100%;}
.booked { background:#F2AE30; }
```

image is attached:

[image]

Comment: We can see on the image that it's only covering the height of the text, so you can't get a same height for all elements if some use one lines and other more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if

```
.available { background:#98AEB3; display:block; height:100%;padding:0;margin:0;}
```

doesn't help, try adding:

```
.available { background:#98AEB3; display:block; height:100%;line-height:18px;}
```

play around with the line-height pixels to tweak it, should work.

Answer (score 1):

A and SPAN are not block elements, therefore they shouldn't have width and height. Also, giving to height a value of 100% isn't interpretated the same way in all browsers.
As you seem to just want to change the background color of the content of the cell, I'd suggest you give the classes .available and .booked to the TD instead of the A tag.

Comment: Where a and span are not block elements, the OP has changed this in CSS.

Comment: And if you want the link to cover the whole cell (working when you click anywhere in the cell), remove the link and add a onclick function on your cell.

Comment: he does have `display:block` on the `a` in his CSS. But I do agree, that best solution is to put the `available` class on the `td`, instead of putting on the anchor tag.